# MySQL 5.7 Escape forward slashes in JSON_EXTRACT key string

Tags: php, mysql, json

Quite simple problem that I can't find a solution for.

I have a simple JSON string:

```
{
  "A/B/C":"Random value"
}
```

It's stored in a MySQL database.  I am trying to use `JSON_EXTRACT` to retrieve the data.

```
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT(`json_data`, "$.A/B/C") AS 'A/B/C'
FROM `MyTable` 
WHERE 1
```

This of course throws an error due to the slashes.  How can I query with the slashes without removing them from the original JSON?

Comment: using "repalce" function? and replace them with an empty string?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Sure.  It has been considered that, using replace like `JSON_EXTRACT(REPLACE(`json_data`, '/', ''), "$.ABC") AS 'A/B/C'` would work.  I am going to see if there is an alternative.  Meanwhile I will use this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the results you want by quoting the key name in double quotes; this is required as it contains illegal path characters (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-paths)). This means you need to enclose the overall path in single quotes:

```
SET @json = '{
  "A/B/C":"Random value"
}'
;
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$."A/B/C"') AS 'A/B/C'
```

Output:

```
A/B/C
"Random value"
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tB6maBwGhNmeYt7Jyqd62Q/0)